# xsl IF statement using property of a serialized object

Tags: xml, xslt, if-statement

Basically I want to make an if statement that only shows the date of the object if the date isn't the default (1-1-1900)

I'm programming it in VB and then its all been successfully put into xsl apart from this date situation, essentially this is what I'm trying to achieve

```
 <tr><th>DateLogged</th><th width ="500">
      <xsl:if NOT = "<xsl:value-of select="DateLogged" /> = 1-1-1900">
        <xsl:value-of select="DateLogged" />
      </xsl:if>
      </th></tr>
```

I've never done any xsl before today so any pointers would be very handy! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this XSLT, which should test whether the **DateLogged** element is literally set to '1-1-1900'

```
<xsl:if test="DateLogged != '1-1-1900'">
    <xsl:value-of select="DateLogged" />
</xsl:if>
```

Of, if you wanted to do away with **xsl:if** condition entirely, you could this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="DateLogged[. != '1-1-1900']" />
```

Comment: Thankyou! the conditional statement worked perfectly, however I did have an issue with the dates not comparing the minutes properly so within VB I converted them to strings and then repeated the statement